# javascript profanity filter error

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, filter

I have this code here:

```
var regex = /smell(y)?|poo/ig;  //Banned Words


function countInArray(array, what) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === what) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

function profanity() {
  var array = [];
  $('font').each( function() {
    var string = $(this).html();
    var pos = countInArray(array, $(this));
    array.push($(this));
    var updatedString = string.replace( regex, function(s) {
      var i = 0;
      var asterisks = "<span title='Blocked Word/Phrase!\nBlocked By Profanity Filter'>";
        while (i < s.length) {
          asterisks += "*";
          i++;
        }
      asterisks = asterisks.concat("</span>");
      $('font').html(asterisks)[pos];
    });
  });
}
```

The code basically scans through each font element for the banned words, however I cannot get it to replace the text for that element only all elements or none at all, I have tried to make an array which will add the value then scan for how many times it is there to try and get it but I am still having problems, can anyone help. I have searched everywhere, but I cannot find or replicate my problem anywhere. Can anyone help me, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't this sort of stuff be done server-side? What's it filtering more precisely?

Comment: By the way, the `font` element has been deprecated (invalid HTML) for a long time. Might be time to remove it from your documents...